# Sitecore SXA with Bootstrap 4

Tags: sxa, responsive-design

Which bootstrap versions are compatible with sitecore SXA 1.5? Current Sitecore SXA comes with bootstrap 3.3.7. Has anyone tried using bootstrap 4? What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 2):

To make it compatible with most of the devices, Sitecore SXA is using bootstrap 3. but any framework can be adapted. you can add the new bootstrap 4 grid and follow the existing bootstrap structure and and modify the classes based on bootstrap 4. see image below:

[image]

**Pros:**

- Introduced flexbox for better designing layouts
- Because of more demand using sass instead of less
- Mixins classes like rounded-corners introduced, to fast up the pace of development
- Fonts using rem for better view on different devices

**Cons:**

- Bootstrap 3 has support for IE9 and iOS6. but flexbox are not supported on these browsers
- Difficult for quick adaption for those who are using bootstrap 3
- Media query breakpoints are changed because of the newly introduced device resolutions, which bootstrap 4 has catered.
- Online customiser in not available